# Assign pair of raw pointers returned by a function to unique_ptr

Tags: pointers, c++11, smart-pointers

I've looked around a little bit but couldn't find an answer to this.

I have a function returning a pair of pointers to objects, the situation can be simplified to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <memory>

std::pair<int *, int *> shallow_copy()
{

   int *i = new int;
   int *j = new int;

   *i = 5;
   *j = 7;

   return std::make_pair(i, j);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   std::pair<int *, int *> my_pair = shallow_copy();

   std::cout << "a = " << my_pair.first << " b = " << *my_pair.second << std::endl;

   // This is just creating a newpointer:
   std::unique_ptr<int> up(my_pair.first);

   std::cout << "a = " << &up << std::endl;

   delete my_pair.first;
   delete my_pair.second;

   return 0;
}
```

I cannot change the return value of the function. From `std::cout << "a = " << &up << std::endl;` I can see that the address of the smart pointer is different from the address of the raw pointer.

Is there a way to capture tha `std::pair` returned by the function in a `std::unique_ptr` and prevent memory leaks without calling `delete` explicitly?

**NB:** The question have been edited to better state the problem and make me look smarter!

Comment: so what's the problem? you are already doing this…

Comment: The problem is that the smart pointer and the raw pointer points to different adresses.

Comment: @drkg4b No, they don't. You're comparing the address *in* `first` with the address *of* `up`. You'll want to print `up.get()` instead of `&up`.

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Crossant: `&*up` would work, but is pretty bad style. I would rather not see that idea even given to anyone.

Comment: @RaoulSteffen why would it be "bad style"? it's perfectly idiomatic in C++. (think iterators…)

Comment: I see now! I'm not a programmer unfortunately! But even doing something like `std::unique_ptr<int> _first(shallow_copy().first);` would require freeing the memory manually right?

Comment: @drkg4b Most definitely not (at least not for the pointer in `first`). Once a block of dynamically allocated memory is managed by a `unique_ptr`, it will be deallocated by the `unique_ptr`'s destructor. In fact, your code contains a double `delete` if the block referred to by `my_pair.first`, because you do it manually, and then `up` will `delete` it again when it goes out of scope.

Comment: @Angew So I could in principle just leave something like `std::unique_ptr<int> _first(shallow_copy().first);` and don't have to care of freeing the memory? If I run with valgrind it says that I have leak though, maybe there's something I'm missing!

Comment: @drkg4b You're of course leaking the memory pointed to by `.second`. You'll have to capture both in smart pointers to prevent leakage.

Comment: @Angew I see! How can I capture both in a smart pointer?

Comment: @drkg4b in no way. you capture them in *two* smart pointers.

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant: Because `&*up` dereferences the pointer, even though you only want the address. What if it is a nullptr?

Comment: @RaoulSteffen you are supposed to have validated the pointer already. IOW, you would first do `if (!up) { /* handle error */ }` **anyway** if you wanted to be safe, even if you used `get`. (Also, is it not the case that when `&` precedes `*` immediately, neither of them are evaluated?)

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Crossaint: If you have a validated pointer, `&*` of cause works. But why rely on a prerequisite, that you don't need? Especially in a debugging case like this, where you don't even know if your presumed prerequisites hold. Also: Of cause `&*` is evaluated. What else should happen in `&*up`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it the right way, but testing it the wrong one. You're comparing the address *in* `first` with the address *of* `up`. If you print `up.get()` instead (the address stored *in* `up`), you'll find they're equal.

In addition, your code has a double-delete problem. You do `delete my_pair.first;`, which deallocates the memory block pointed to by `my_pair.first` and also by `up`. Then, the destructor of `up` will deallocate it again when `up` goes out of scope, resulting in a double delete.

You also asked how to capture both pointers in smart pointers. Since the constructor of `std::unique_ptr` taking a raw pointer is explicit, you cannot directly do this with a simple `std::pair<std::unique_ptr<int>, std::unique_ptr<int>>`. You can use a helper function, though:

```
std::pair<std::unique_ptr<int>, std::unique_ptr<int>> wrapped_shallow_copy()
{
  auto orig = shallow_copy();
  std::pair<std::unique_ptr<int>, std::unique_ptr<int>> result;
  result.first.reset(orig.first);
  result.second.reset(orig.second);
  return result;
}
```

Now, use `wrapped_shallow_copy()` instead of `shallow_copy()` and you will never leak memory from the call.

Comment: Thanks! Perhaps I should restate the original question

Comment: @drkg4b I think that would help. Try extending it with the info you've provided in comments, preferably without invalidating my answer. I think it has the potential of a good question in it.

Comment: I edited it, seems to me that it doesn't invalidate your answer and that its a better stated question now!